# A command from the RDF4J framework is throwing an error

Tags: ontology, semantic-web, graphdb, rdf4j

When running the following commands, an error is thrown by the add command. The **rdf4j** framework is used for communicating with a [graphdb](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/) Knowledge Base:

```
 import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Model;

Model model;
//statements have been added to the model

 public RepositoryConnection connection;
 ...
 connection.add(model); <-- error is thrown
```

An error is thrown in add command

```
2022-01-24 09:46:02 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR restapi.SubmitRMService - unable to rollback transaction. HTTP error code 404
org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryException: unable to rollback transaction. HTTP error code 404
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.client.RDF4JProtocolSession.rollbackTransaction(RDF4JProtocolSession.java:786)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.http.HTTPRepositoryConnection.rollback(HTTPRepositoryConnection.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.base.AbstractRepositoryConnection.conditionalRollback(AbstractRepositoryConnection.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.base.AbstractRepositoryConnection.add(AbstractRepositoryConnection.java:379)
```

The code is running successfully in two other environments except one we are setting with kubernetes. We ensured that */opt/graphdb/home* has write permissions.

**Question:** I just do not understand the 404 RepositoryException error. The code can successfully run queries before the *.add(model)*, so the connection with the graphdb is ok.

Comment: This sounds like something going wrong with the transaction handling, at either server or client end. Which version of the RDF4J libraries are you using at the client side, and which version of GraphDB are you running on the server? Also: is there anything showing in the GraphDB server logs?

Comment: did you start the transaction (connection.begin())? this 404 looks like there's no transaction or if there's a proxy in front of graphdb you might need graphdb-external-url config, see here https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/configuring-graphdb.html#url-properties (you most likely need this for k8s as well)

Comment: Thanks for your hints, finally it was that the graphdb was not setup for https requests and it was not obvious in the logs